# How to count files inside folders and subfolders with PHP

Tags: php

Is there a effective way to count files inside a single folder which inside it have more files and subfolders?

I tried something like this, still didn't give me the right number. Windows recognise there are 159 files inside Images folder. When I only get 144

```
<?php
$img = count(glob("./assets/images/*.*"));
$about = count(glob("./assets/images/aboutus/*.*"));
$blog1 = count(glob("./assets/images/blog/*.*"));
$mason = count(glob("./assets/images/blog/masonary/*.*"));
$tl = count(glob("./assets/images/blog/timeline/*.*"));
$blog2 = count(glob("./assets/images/blogdetails/*.*"));
$gallery = count(glob("./assets/images/gallery/*.*"));
$home = count(glob("./assets/images/home/*.*"));
$keg = count(glob("./assets/images/kegiatan/*.*"));
$port1 = count(glob("./assets/images/portfolio/*.*"));
$port2 = count(glob("./assets/images/portfolio-details/*.*"));
$srv = count(glob("./assets/images/services/*.*"));
$usr = count(glob("./assets/images/users/*.*"));
$count = $img+$about+$blog1+$mason+$tl+$blog2+$gallery+$home+$keg+$port1+$port2+$srv+$usr;
?>
```

Help??

EDITED:
Done. My mistakes. I didn't count the subfolders in certain folder.

But still, is there a way to make it short?

Comment: With `recursivedirectoryiterator` maybe?

Comment: If anything helped you, you should mark the question answered. Or answer your own question

Comment: I still didn't get it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start of what you could try. You still need to modify it to count the files or count the array that is given.

```
function getFromDir( $dir ) {
    $cdir = scandir( $dir );
    $result = array();

    foreach( $cdir as $key => $value ) {
        if( !in_array( $value, array('.', '..') ) ) {
            if( is_dir( $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value ) ) {
                $result[$value] = getFromDir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
            } else {
                $result[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

If you would pass `"./assets/images/"` as a paramater it should get all sub folders aswell.

So you end up with something like:

```
$count = count(getFromDir("./assets/images/"));
```

Comment: I don't know how to implement this into Codeigniter

Comment: Maybe you should ask a second question about that with Codeigniter. Do not update this question as it won't be seen by much people because it is already deep in the questions list